# Couchbase Query to shard data in collections

Tags: couchbase

I have millions of records in legacy couchbase bucket. Post migration to couchbase 7.0 it will be copied to _default scope and collection now If I need to shard it across collections. Say collections are per month and year what query should I write
which will take data from bucketname_default_default to respective collection for month i.e. collection named collection_month_year. I have createdDate in the document already.

Comment: There are multiple approaches to this. You could use SQL++ queries. Another approach involves Eventing - https://www.couchbase.com/blog/migrating-buckets-to-collections-scopes-via-eventing-part-1/

Comment: Use caution with any approach that requires the number of collections to grow over time, since there's a limit on the number of collections you can create. (1000, last time I checked).

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider using XDCR: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/clusters-and-availability/xdcr-with-scopes-and-collections.html#migration